# What's the way to know if the view is for GET or POST in javascript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

MVC use action attributes to map the same view for http get or post:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return View();
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
 MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel(id);
 return View();
}
```

Question is: in javascript, how can I know if the view is for http get command or http post command?

Comment: What's your usecase? I would like to think that the View should not care about how it was invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a little bit of javascript on the page to indicate whether the request generating the view was a get or post.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var requestMethod = '<%= ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod %>';
</script>
```